# Sort td values on multiple tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to sort the first `td` elements of 3 tables. I must use jQuery to do it not pure javascript. Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cx</td>
        <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>bx</td>
        <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ax</td>
        <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The result I would like to get is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ax</td>
        <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>bx</td>
        <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cx</td>
        <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Edit 1: that is what I'm trying to do: if you just could tell me how to get the current td element value it would be nice for me

Edit 2: Now The values in the result is the same as before sorting. Sorry for my mistake

```
var table = $("table");
var currentTableTd;
$.each(table, function(k, v) {
  //currentTableTd = v.find("td:first-child");
  //window.console.log(currentTableTd); // will log error v.find() is not a function which I understand because var v isn't a Jquery object.
  //or
  currentTableTd = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
  window.console.log(currentTableTd); //log undefined
})
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: The values in the result is not the same as before sorting?

Comment: you could use tablesorter plugins available -> http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Introduction if it is not an issue

Comment: Also paste your jquery code, if you have any then we can help you to make it proper

Comment: you can call a function to sort every table. Why are you trying to loop the table?

Comment: @Arg0n Sorry it was a mistake I made when typing on my keyboard. Now the result is the same as before sorting.

Comment: @Bharat Jain: thank you for helping. I have those table in the same page. I thought I had to use a loop to solve my problem.

Comment: @zm455: Does this suggestions solved your problem?

Comment: @Parag Bhayani I used the solution posted by benG: I didn't know it was so easy sorting tables with jquery.  Than you for your help sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), then replace the `html`:-

```js
var sorted = $('table').sort(function(a, b) {
  return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());
}).clone();

sorted.each(function(i, e) {
  $('table').eq(i).html($(e).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cx</td>
    <td>xx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>bx</td>
    <td>xx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ax</td>
    <td>xx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after working on this problem during 24hours I have found my own solution. I post it here. Maybe it could helps other people.

Special thanks to those people who "voted down" on my question without helping me. They gave me the willpower to find my own solution.

```
    var table = $("table");
    $.each(table, function (k, v) {
        var $currentTable = $("table").eq(k);
        var $tr = $currentTable.find("tr").not(":first");
        var $tdAll = $tr.find("td:first");
        var textNodes = []; //collecting textNodes of td elements 
        var map = {}; //mapping $tdAll
        var result = []; //contains sorted td elements to be added to the dom

        $.each($tdAll, function (k, v) {
            textNodes.push($(v).text());
            map[k] = $(v);
        })
        textNodes.sort();
        for (var i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i++) {
            for (var key in map) {
                if (textNodes[i] === $(map[key]).text())
                    result.push($(map[key]));
            }
        }
        //Dom construction
        $tr.find("td").remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i++) {
            $tr.eq(i).find("td:first").before($(result[i]));
        }
    })
```